# How to get selected text from edittext in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have a edittext in which some text are selected . I want to get only selected text from edittext on click of button .

Please suggest me usable link or sample code.

Comment: [Search](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4531500/420015)

Comment: [Have a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8909122/593709)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

int startSelection=et.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection=et.getSelectionEnd();

String selectedText = et.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
```

Comment: after it if u want to check whether selectedtext is empty or not. you must use isEmpty function .

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin**

```
val startSelection: Int = editText.selectionStart
val endSelection: Int = editText.selectionEnd

val selectedText: String = editText.text.substring(startSelection, endSelection)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getSelectionStart()
getSelectionEnd()
```

see this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getSelectionEnd%28%29)