# How to get single string from edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need only string at current cursor position not all the string from edittext. For example, If I am typing "Hello world, how are you all?" then, if my cursor is at "are" then I need only string "are".

Comment: if the cursor is in middle then i will manage I need only the currently typed text in edittext at cursor position

Comment: I have tried using ontextchanged listener and using the charsequence and count. But I need shorter way to get the string at current cursor position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `EditText.getSelectionStart()` to get the current position of the cursor

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

int startSelection=et.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection=et.getSelectionEnd();

String selectedText = et.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
```

Take a look here [How to get selected text from edittext in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070762/how-to-get-selected-text-from-edittext-in-android)

Comment: As per the OP's description, the text is not selected.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using pattern in Android.

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
Spannable textSpan = editText.getText();
final int selection = editText.getSelectionStart();
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textSpan);
int start = 0;
int end = 0;

String currentWord = "";
while (matcher.find()) {
    start = matcher.start();
    end = matcher.end();
    if (start <= selection && selection <= end) {
        currentWord = textSpan.subSequence(start, end).toString();
    }
}
Log.d("value", currentWord);
```

Comment: If this answer solved your query, you should mark this as correct @OP